# How to undo hg init?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I typed `hg init` in a directory, but then changed my mind: I'd rather not have this under version control. So how do I undo `hg init`?

I suppose there is another solution than deleting `.hg` directories, but I couldn't find the command. Or is it impossible for mercurial to remove itself from a project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why don't using

`rm -rv .hg/` on Linux/Unix systems or under MacOS

or

`rmdir /S .hg` on WIndows systems (with the good ol' cmdline, the first example works under the PowerShell too).

It's simple and effective and does what you want: Removing Mercurial from the project.

Comment: +1 for giving an actual command, though no OS being specified in the question, the Windows equivalent would be a nice addition ;)

Comment: All three posts answered my question at the same time. In this case I accept the one from the user with the least reputation score.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing `hg init` does is adding the `.hg` directory and its contents.

So, undoing a `hg init` can indeed be done by simply deleting the `.hg` directory. It really cannot get any easier than this!

Comment: Okay, I figured there should be a command. I guess the "don't touch the `.hg`" advice does not apply in this case.

Comment: That advice is to *prevent breaking it*, in this case you **want to break** it ;)

Answer (score 6):

Just delete the `.hg` directory (it's just one, at the root of the repository). There's nothing more to it.